# Treat local files as being in intranet zone in Internet Explorer

Tags: configuration, internet-explorer

I am trying to get Internet Explorer to treat a file or files in a certain directory on the local hdd as being in the Intranet Zone. I can make this work by deploying the files to an IIS server and adding that server to the intranet zone in the IE security settings, and I can also make it work by setting up a unc share to point at a local disk and adding this to the intranet zone. I can't seem to get this to work with a local file path though.

This is an example of the path that I would like to be able to add:

file:///D:/work/svn/client/trunk/src/Test.Silverlight.UI/Bin/Debug/TestPage.html

I have also tried wildcard paths - e.g.

file:///D:/work/svn/*

and both attempts display an error message saying:

```
> You have entered an invalid wildcard
> sequence. Examples of valid patterns:
>   *://*.microsoft.com
>   http://*.microsoft.co.jp
>   ftp://157.54.23.41/
>   file:\\localsvr\share
>   *://157.54.100-200.* Examples of
> invalid patterns:
>   http://microsoft.*.com  ftp://*
```

Is this possible with Internet Explorer or is it prohibited for some reason? I'm using IE8.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could probably do it if you used UNC paths:

file:\computername\d$\etc\etc...

Then open the file in IE using the same path.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this, it doesn't seem to work though - the file is still treated as being in the internet zone - odd, as I thought this would work :)